# What do these arguments mean in swagger_auto_schema (Django)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

The project uses a swagger.
There is the following code.

```
@swagger_auto_schema(
        manual_parameters=[
            Parameter('download', IN_QUERY,
                      'Set `Content-Disposition=attachment` to make browser to download file'
                      'instead of showing it.',
                      type='bool'),
            Parameter('share_id', IN_PATH, type='uuid')
        ],
        security=[],
        responses={'400': 'Validation Error (e.g. base64 is wrong)',
                   '200': VideoSerializer}
    )
```

Please explain what each argument is responsible for.
I read the documentation, but understood little ...
Particularly interested in `'200': VideoSerializer`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`responses`**

The responses argument is a dictionary of possible responses that this endpoint can return.

`400` and `200` are [HTTP response codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), Bad Request and OK respectively.

In this case, this means that this endpoint can generate two types of responses:

- Bad request which will also return (as described) a Validation Error which means that something in the request was incorrect, which means it could not be handled correctly.
- OK, which means the request is correct, and everything was handled correctly. `VideoSerializer` means that a response will be given with accordance to the structure of the `VideoSerializer`, which defines a collection of fields.

---

The other two arguments:

**`manual_parameters`**

This a custom list of parameters that can be added to the request to customize the response. 
In this case, two parameters are defined:

- `download` : A query parameter of type bool. Query parameters are passed like this : `example.com?query_parameter=true
- `share_id`, a path parameter of type 'uuid'. Path parameters are passed like this : `example.com/path_parameter`

**`security`**
A list of security schemes that the request must adhere to. Used for instance for Basic authentication.